# URL Rewriting in .htaccess - getting confused with params

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite, parameters

I searched in the web to find a valid solution for my problem, but nothing works.
Hopefully you guys can help me.

I want to Rewrite a URL on an Apache doing like that:

(1.) www.example.com/en/rainbow.html => www.example.com/index.php?site=rainbow&lang=en

or

(2.) www.example.com/rainbow.html =>www.example.com/index.php?site=rainbow&lang=

or

(3.) www.example.com//rainbow.html =>www.example.com/index.php?site=rainbow&lang=

To be honest, my understanding for regex isn't that good.

Tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)[/](.+).html|(.+).html$ index.php/?lang=$1&site=$2 [QSA]
```

Result: No Error, but "site" has only a param at (1.).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*[/]){0,1}(.*).html$ index.php/?lang=$1&site=$2 [QSA]
```

Result: Works fine, but i.e. lang="en/", should be lang="en"

In which way I can improve it and let it work correct?!

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (/en/)?([^/]+)\.html$ index.php/?site=$2lang=$1 [QSA]
```

No need to escape forward slashes in mod-rewrite, by the way. But you do need to escape the `.`, which, as you know, stands in as a wildcard in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in url rewriting, but i like koalas:

```
RewriteRule /+(([^/]+)/)?([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php/?site=$3&lang=$2 [QSA]
```